# Pixi JS Graphics: Resize Circle while maintaining center

Tags: javascript, geometry, html5-canvas, centering, pixi.js

I'm trying to resize a graphic circle by looping the scale method. The loop will animate the circle's scale from 1 to 3 then 3 to 1. The code below works as I intended it to however, when the circle enlarges, it resizes to the direction of bottom-right. Then, the circle resizes back to its opposite direction (top-left) after reaching the given max scale. Here's the code:

```
const app = new PIXI.Application({
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
});

const canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv');
canvasDiv.appendChild(app.view);

let circle = new PIXI.Graphics();
circle.beginFill(0xffffff);
circle.drawCircle(5, 5, 5);
circle.x = 150;
circle.y = 150;
circle.endFill();
app.stage.addChild(circle);

let scale = 1, motion = 1;

app.ticker.add(() => animateLoop());

function animateLoop(){
    if (motion == 1){
        if (scale < 3){
            scale += 0.2;
        }
        else{
            motion = 0;
        }
    }
    else{
        if (scale > 1){
            scale -= 0.2;
        }
        else{
            motion = 1;
        }
    }
    circle.scale.set(scale,scale);
}
```

I've read the Pixi site and saw the option pivot to handle the centering of the graphics during resizing. I tried impementing it, and it does have slight improvements. However, I'm not able to exactly center the circle despite trying multiple pivot values. Here's the added code:

```
/** On Motion 1 */
if (scale < 3){
    scale += 0.2;
    circle.pivot.x += 0.5;
    circle.pivot.y += 0.2;
}
/** On Motion 0 */
if (scale > 1){
    scale -= 0.2;
    circle.pivot.x -= 0.5;
    circle.pivot.y -= 0.2;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pivot point is a location somwhere inside an object's local coordinate space.

If you take a look at the following illustration:

[image]

you can see that the top-left corner is at x: 0 | y: 0 while the lower-right is at x: circle.width | y: circle.height.

That means if we want to scale the circle from within it's center we need to move the pivot point to the center of it! (x: circle.width/2 | y: circle.height/2)

Here's an example:

```js
const app = new PIXI.Application({
  width: 400,
  height: 300,
  backgroundColor: 0x1099bb,
  resolution: window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

const container = new PIXI.Container();

let circle = new PIXI.Graphics();
circle.beginFill(0x00ffff);
circle.drawCircle(50, 50, 50);

circle.endFill();
circle.x = 200;
circle.y = 150;
circle.pivot.x = circle.width / 2;
circle.pivot.y = circle.height / 2;
app.stage.addChild(circle);

let scale = 1,
  motion = 1;

app.ticker.add(() => animateLoop());

function animateLoop() {
  if (motion == 1) {
    if (scale < 3) {
      scale += 0.1;
    } else {
      motion = 0;
    }
  } else {
    if (scale > 1) {
      scale -= 0.1;
    } else {
      motion = 1;
    }
  }
  circle.scale.set(scale, scale);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pixijs.download/release/pixi.js"></script>
```